# Windows 11 Upgrade setup fails at 0% with "SPInitializeMonitoringDriver: SETUPMON: Failed to load the monitoring filter driver"

Tags: windows, windows-11, windows-11-upgrade

I am trying to upgrade my PC to Windows 11. When I run the setup.exe, I continue the process until I get the full page screen showing the progress.

As soon as I get it, it fails at 0% with this error message popup "windows 11 installation has failed"

I tried to inspect the logs, here is what I see:

```
2021-11-04 22:17:39, Info                  SP         SPInitializeMonitoringDriver: SETUPMON: VERBOSE: Tracking Config -- END
2021-11-04 22:17:39, Info                  SP         SPInitializeMonitoringDriver: SETUPMON: Monitoring filter driver installed successfully.
2021-11-04 22:17:39, Error                            WsmLoad: Failed FilterLoad(); hr = 0x800700a1
2021-11-04 22:17:39, Error                 SP         SPInitializeMonitoringDriver: SETUPMON: Failed to load the monitoring filter driver. Error: 0x800700A1
2021-11-04 22:17:39, Error                 SP         SETUPMON: Failed to install/start monitoring driver. Error: 0x800700A1
2021-11-04 22:17:39, Info                  SP     <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
2021-11-04 22:17:39, Error                 SP     Operation failed: Start Monitoring Driver. Error: 0x800700A1[gle=0x000000b7]
2021-11-04 22:17:39, Info                  SP     Operation can retry, we'll attempt to revert its execution.
2021-11-04 22:17:39, Info                  SP     Attempt to revert execution for operation 2
2021-11-04 22:17:39, Error                 SP     COperationQueue::Sort: Could not find an execution phase for 2
2021-11-04 22:17:39, Error                 SP     ExecuteOperations: Operations cannot be sorted. This is a fatal failure.
2021-11-04 22:17:39, Error                 SP     ExecuteOperations: Main operation execution failed. Error: 0x8007000D
2021-11-04 22:17:39, Error                 SP     ExecuteOperations: Failed execution phase Downlevel. Error: 0x8007000D
2021-11-04 22:17:39, Info                  MOUPG  MoSetupPlatform: SetupPlatform::INewSystem::ExecuteCurrentOperations returned: [0x4]
2021-11-04 22:17:39, Error                 MOUPG  MoSetupPlatform: ExecuteCurrentOperations reported failure![gle=0x8007000d]
2021-11-04 22:17:39, Error                 MOUPG  CDlpActionImageDeploy::ExecuteRoutine(537): Result = 0xC1900101[gle=0x8007000d]
2021-11-04 22:17:39, Info                  MOUPG  MoSetupPlatform: SuspendAndReleasing NewSystem object...
```

.

```
Error: SetupDiag reports abrupt down-level failure.
Last Operation: Finalize
Error: 0xC1900101 - 0x50010
LogEntry: 2021-11-04 22:17:39, Error                 MOUPG  CDlpActionImageDeploy::ExecuteRoutine(537): Result = 0xC1900101[gle=0x8007000d]

Refer to "https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/Debug/system-error-codes" for error information.

Last Setup Phase:
Phase Name: Downlevel
    Phase Started: 04-11-2021 22:17:39
    Phase Ended: 01-01-0001 00:00:00
    Phase Time Delta: 00:00:00
    Completed Successfully? False


Last Setup Operation:
Operation Name: Start Monitoring Driver
    Operation Started: 04-11-2021 22:17:39
    Operation Ended: 01-01-0001 00:00:00
    Operation Time Delta: 0:00:00:00.0000000
    Completed Successfully? False
```

Here is what I have done so far:

- Enable TPM and Secure Boot
- Uninstall Vera Crypt, Avast, and Acronis Software's.
- Suspending bitlocker on system drive.
- I also tried booting from Windows 11 USB drive and upgrade from there, but it tells me to run the installer from the Windows 10 desktop instead.

But I have no luck so far.

Comment: Try disabling signed signatures. This might be due to an expired certificate that signed a driver.

Comment: You will want to disable BitLocker protection to try that solution by the way. Secure Boot will have to remain on

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue. It has something to do with "Volume Shadow Copy Service".

Here is what you should do in case you face similar issues.

1. Run `fltmc filters` and `fltmc instances`.
2. Try to uninstall all the Software using filters in this list.
3. Also stop and disable the "Volume Shadow Copy" service in `services.msc`.

It should do the job.

Answer (score 0):

You need 4 things for a proper upgrade to Windows 11 (running here).

1. UEFI instead of legacy BIOS.
2. Secure Boot.
3. TPMv2
4. CPU less than 4 years old.

You said you have #2.
You said you enabled TPM. Is it V2?  .
Is your drive UEFI and GPT?  .
Is the CPU less than 4 years old? .

When you run Windows Update, does it offer Windows 11? Or does it say "This PC does not currently meet the requirements to upgrade to Windows 11?

If all systems are go, you probably should wait for Windows Update to be ready for you.

Comment: I tried the PC compatibility check application earlier. So I am pretty sure it's TPM 2.0 and recent CPU (it's Intel 8700).  Disk Management say my disc is GPT.

Comment: Check to make sure your computer is using UEFI (there will be a UEFI partition) and then you may need to wait for Windows Update to be ready.

Comment: Yes, there is UEFI too. I have disabled Windows update a long time ago. I am using the ISO file from the official website. It's not working in the step I mentioned.

Comment: Try updating Windows 10 to the latest version. Windows Updates should not be disabled.